# Multiple Classes in SVG

Tags: javascript, class, svg, d3.js

I'm very new to SVG (using D3.js to call everything). Recently, I just came into a huge limitation with a project I am working on. I want to be able to make "g" classes for each category of data I am working with. Unfortunately, I am getting my data from an XML file that only connects data in one way (ex: person1 ---> person2, but not person2 ---> person1). What I would like to be able to do is to put each shape generated from my data in the root class AND the class it is connecting with. If I could add this shape to two or more classes (such as g class = person1 and person2), that would be the fastest solution I believe...But is something like this possible? Can I set an SVG shape to two or more classes? Or will it overwrite it as I define new ones.

I really hope someone can understand what I am asking. It is kind of hard to verbalize my problem without giving away every detail of my final project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can set multiple classes. For example,

```
<g class="person1 person2">
```

Or, in D3:

```
g.attr("class", "person1 person2");
```

Comment: This is incredible news. The workaround my boss suggested was probably going to take me nearly a month (he's not fluent in JS, D3, or English so it was very hard to explain why his approach was too bulky). With this knowledge, I can be done in a week or so.

Comment: Also, thank you for all your work! I just got a data visualization internship a few weeks back. I was given the task to work on a highly dynamic network visualization. After some research, I went with d3 as my main drawing library. Your github gallery and the tutorials you have posted have carried me through every step of this project.

Answer (score 0):

One more note:  If you're calling a function from within a file:

```
.attr("class",function(d) { return d.person1+" "+ d.person2;}  )
```